# django merging two querysets or two annotations with filter

Tags: django, django-models

I got this table:

Visit:

```
member | room | status
'john' | 1    | 1 (successful)
'paul' | 1    | 2 (cancelled)
'john' | 1    | 1 (successful)
'john' | 1    | 2 (cancelled)
```

And I want to get this:

Visits:

```
member | successful | cancelled
'john' | 2          | 1
'paul' | 0          | 1
```

I tries using two annotations with filter, but sure, I know I was wrong...

```
obj_visits = obj_visits.annotate(successful=Count('status')).filter(status=1)
obj_visits = obj_visits.annotate(cancelled=Count('status')).filter(status=2)
```

Then I separated these annotations and merge those results in one

```
obj_visits_approved = Visit.objects.values('member').annotate(successful=Count('status')).filter(status=1)
obj_visits_cancelled = Visit.objects.values('member').annotate(cancelled=Count('status')).filter(status=2)
```

I get two results:

```
member | successful
'john' | 2
'paul' | 0

member | cancelled
'john' | 1
'paul' | 1
```

if I chain those results I get 4 rows... I can't use `obj_visits= obj_visits_approved | obj_visits_cancelled` because it says that classes must involve the same values in each case...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by just grouping with the `member` and `status` [using a `values` and `annotate` query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses), like so:

```
obj_visits = Visit.objects.values('member','status').annotate(number=Count('status'))
```

Comment: thanks, this results a table with columns [member_id, status, number].. a row for every status member has... is there something else I can do to make a table like [member_id, successful_count, cancelled_count] ?

Comment: Probably not. But transforming the query from `[member_id, status, number]` to `[member_id, successful_count, cancelled_count]` in code is probably more straight forward, and less burdensome than doing it through SQL.

Comment: You can probably do it using raw SQL calls, but you'd need to know how to construct those calls yourself.